# Change the Existing class name in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, classname

I have xcode 4.5 and I want to add two project's file in my project.
But the problem is - In that two class both class's name are same.
I changed the Class prefix from file inspector but it is changing the newly added file's name.
not my existing class name.

How to change all the existing class name or single class name ?

Comment: Didn't understand -`I changed the Class prefix from file inspector but it is changing the newly added file's name.
not my existing class name.`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Select your class name in .h/.m file
2. Goto **Edit->Refactor->Rename**
3. Enter the new name for the class

Comment: Thanks bro... I am giving you 1+

Comment: If I rename a class like this, if I am to change its name back to what it was before renaming I get an error: "Class of same name already exists" . Any idea ?

Comment: @pe60t0 I didn't get an error like that.. probably clean your product and try again fix your problem

Comment: Just wanted to point out I had the same issue as @pe60t0 with the "Class of same name already exists" error, and I restarted XCode to fix it.

Comment: Helpful tip - select the class name in the .m file just after `@interface`, and make sure there is no whitespace on either side of it.